# Как создать копию ветки с удаленного репозитория?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout

Как создать копию ветки с удаленного репозитория?

Comment: хорошая дока по git вызывается командой 

    git help
 
и потом например 

    git help checkout


а где второй  вопрос ?

Comment: пока что не придумал, но скоро будет

Comment: кто отмодерировал вопрос ? вы русский язык знаете ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Эта команда создаст локальную копию удаленной ветки

```
git checkout -b remote_branch origin/remote_branch
```

Comment: Разве она не копирует ветку существующего репозитория просто удаленным вариантом?

Comment: По-моему этого вопрощающий и хотел добиться, или я неправильно понял вопрос?

Comment: Дело в том что если руководствоваться вашей командой - то клонируется с этого же оригина ветка с удаленного командой git checkout branch

если же самому приходиться ветку создавать - то ее нужно создать уже на удаленном хосте 

а с удаленного так или иначе нужно брать ветку вариантом ниже... ибо оригин - это есть тот что есть репо вообще...

может и я вопрос не правильно понял...

Comment: Я вообще не понял вашего последнего комментария, извините.

Answer (score 6):

Современные версии Git позволяют делать это гораздо проще:

```
git checkout branchname
```

Работает, когда:

1. Есть удалённая ветка `origin/branchname`
2. Но нет локальной ветки с именем `branchname`

Допустим, есть удаленная ветка `feature`, которой у вас ещё нет локально.

```
$ git branch --all
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/feature
  remotes/origin/master
```

Достаточно этого:

```
$ git checkout feature
Branch feature set up to track remote branch feature from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'feature'
```

Проверяем:

```
$ git branch --all
* feature
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/feature
  remotes/origin/master
```

Новая ветка действительно отслеживает удалённую:

```
git branch -vv
* feature      ed185c8 [origin/feature] extract environment
  master       4db6d3b [origin/master] stylecheck-driven syntax improvements
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git remote add workflow git://github.com/someuser/somerepo.git
git fetch workflow
git checkout -b remote_branch workflow/somebranch
```

более ли менее подходящий вариант для удаленного другого не относящегося к вашему репозиторию и создание одной из его веток отдельной веткой в вашем репо..

Answer (score 0):

Шаг 1. Проверьте настройки "remote.origin.fetch", должно быть так:

> $ git config --get remote.origin.fetch
>
> +refs/heads/dev_branch:refs/remotes/origin/dev_branch

Шаг 2. Измените «remote.origin.fetch», чтобы получить (fetch) все ветки:

> $ git config remote.origin.fetch "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"
>
> $ git config --get remote.origin.fetch
>
> +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

Затем вы можете попробовать `git pull` или `git checkout dev_branch`, чтобы получить всю ветку.