# Cкачать (fetch) с GitLab содержимое запроса на слияние (merge request)

Tags: git, gitlab, git-remote

Сервер Gitlab, организую работу через запросы на слияние (merge request, pull request).

При создании запроса хотелось бы иметь URL, из которого *Jenkins* смог бы выкачивать последний коммит ветки, которая предлагается к слиянию.

Есть ли возможность в Gitlab получить такой URL?

- какой-нибудь alias к ветке, предлагаемой к слиянию?
- автоматически создаваемый предварительный коммит? (т.е. что бы получилось, если прямо сейчас нажать кнопку <kbd>Merge Request</kbd>?

Знаю, что-то подобное возможно в Gitlab CI и GitHub CI, на этих коммитах даже тесты прогоняются. Поэтому возможен и третий вариант:

- Работать с Jenkins как с Gitlab CI?

Перейти полностью на Gitlab CI - не вариант, это будут неоправданные затраты.

Comment: Похоже, что надо задействовать API, что Jenkins уже знает?

Comment: @D-side я тут внезапно нашёл ответ )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> - автоматически создаваемый предварительный коммит? (т.е. что бы получилось, если прямо сейчас нажать кнопку <kbd>Merge Request</kbd>?

Фича пока не реализована, [можно проголосовать](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/4176).

> - какой-нибудь alias к ветке, предлагаемой к слиянию?

Реализовано. На каждый merge request гитлаб создаёт внутри себя отдельный указатель в `refs/merge-requests`. Нужно просто настроить свой репозиторий, чтобы при `git fetch` забирать эти указатели.

1. Открываем `.git/config`, находим в нём блок, соответствующий репозиторию.

   ```
   [remote "origin"]
     url = https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce.git
     fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
   ```
2. Добавляем в него строку `+refs/merge-requests/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/merge-requests/*`. Теперь должно выглядеть так:

   ```
   [remote "origin"]
     url = https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce.git
     fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
     fetch = +refs/merge-requests/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/merge-requests/*
   ```
3. Обновляем данные:

   ```
   $ git fetch origin
   From https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce.git
    * [new ref]         refs/merge-requests/1/head -> origin/merge-requests/1
    * [new ref]         refs/merge-requests/2/head -> origin/merge-requests/2
   ```
4. Теперь можно [создать новую локальную ветку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/541898/181472), отслеживающую соответствующий merge request.

   ```
   $ git checkout merge-requests/1
   Branch merge-requests/1 set up to track remote branch merge-requests/1 from origin.
   Switched to a new branch 'merge-requests/1'
   ```

Примеры взяты из [документации GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/merge_requests/index.html). Там же есть более подробные инструкции.